# What does the win32api.ShellExecute() function do?

Tags: python, winapi, printing

I'm learning about printing a file in python. I found many ways to do this, One of the most common ways I've seen is using the `win32api` module.

```
import win32api
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", path_for_file , None, ".", 0)
```

When I run this program, the file gets printed without any problems.

But the thing is that I'm not understanding what is actually going on in the `win32api.ShellExecute()` function and what are the functions of it's arguments. By **arugments**, I mean this: `(0, "print", path_for_file , None, ".", 0)`

Can anyone please explain what does each and every argument inside the `win32api.ShellExecute()` function do?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: are you looking for the corresponding winapi doc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew

Comment: As I said, if you don't know what window ownership is, and it's implications for dialogs, then you aren't going to get an answer in this format. You need to do some research.

Comment: That said, your approach to printing is so flaky that parent window handles are the very least of your concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew) documentation:

```
ShellExecute(0,              // NULL since it's not associated with a window
             "print",        // execute the "print" verb defined for the file type
             path_for_file,  // path to the document file to print
             None,           // no parameters, since the target is a document file
             ".",            // current directory, same as NULL here
             0)              // SW_HIDE passed to app associated with the file type
```

In brief, this performs the same action as right-clicking the `path_for_file` document in Windows Explorer, then choosing `print` from the context menu. The app associated with the file type is executed with the `print` verb and `SW_HIDE` show command, which normally means it will print the document silently, without displaying any UI.

Comment: Hi, thanks for explaining, but I did not understand the use of the first, fourth and fifth argument.
Could you please explain the functions of three arguments in a little more detail?

Comment: @Lenovo360 For the 1st see [Handle for ShellExecute() - Parent Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315527) (tl;dr most often `NULL`). For the 4th, if you used `ShellExecute` to run an executable, instead of a verb-by-association, then those parameters would be passed to the target executable on the command line (n/a when launching a document file). More about shell objects and verbs at [Launching Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch) for example.

Comment: ... For the 5th, that's used to set the [current working directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory#remarks) for the target process, and passing a full path there would allow `path-to-file` to use a relative path. However, in your example `"."` *is* the current working directory, so it has the same effect as passing `NULL`, instead.